# I created several child pages in my wordpress website (Home>PYQ>Others) The Issue: When I open the PYQ page, there is a new Nav Button to Home

Tags: wordpress

How do I remove it.. As shown in the image. If I remove the child page option, That Nav Button goes away, else the menu comes back. Am super confused. Generatepress theme..

image for reference

[image: 1]

I have no clue how it appears..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue..
Apparently this code at the sidebar.php was the culprit.

```
</div>
<?php if ( $post->post_parent ) { ?>
 <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>" >
<?php echo get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); ?>
 </a>
<?php } ?>
```

I deleted this part of the code from the editor and now the echo is gone..